# Making a user stylesheet work for multiple websites + URLs

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, safari, include

Is there a way to specify a certain chunk within a custom css stylesheet for a browser to apply to different websites or URLs? For example, Google Chrome's Custom.css or Firefox's userContent.css can be modified to change the appearance of a website, but the changes will apply to every website you visit that share the same tags, id's, classes, etc. Like includes or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox, you can do this using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@document (needs a `-moz` prefix at the moment, since it's non-standard).

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for! I mean it's too bad that it only works with Firefox, but maybe this could lead to something better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox have defined their own css to be a "default" for rendering certain page elements. This is part of the browser, which is why they can let it be global. You, on the other hand, don't have that privilege.

Comment: Any edits to Google Chrome's Custom.css or Firefox's userContent.css apply to every website you visit in the browser automatically. And I'm talking about is modifying websites like Facebook, Twitter, etc, where you can't add a link to a custom stylesheet in the header. Does that make sense?

Comment: @luke Oh I see. That's because it's part of the way chrome and firefox render pages. It's their `default` for how to render certain elements of the page. The reason they can do that is because it's part of the browser. So no, you're not gonna be able to do that. There *might* be a way to edit browser settings and do something like that, but I don't know.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it would be easier to install an extension, but the only good one I know of out there is only for Safari :/

Comment: @luke sounds to me like a good time to learn how to write browser extensions :)

Comment: What you're referring to is a user-agent stylesheet. The question here is about a user stylesheet, which is a different thing; you *can* supply a user stylesheet in addition to the browser defaults to change the way a browser renders one or more sites, albeit only on a per-user basis.